# Solve the random number logic

Tags: php, random, logic

I have a function called `myrand()` which generates random number from 1 to 5. I want to make another function by using `myrand()` that will generate random number form 1 to 7. I write something like that.

```
function newrand() {
    return myrand()+2;
}
```

Above logic is not that I want it will never return me 1 or 2. I don't want to use any if condition so what should I do to make logic for random number.

Comment: Why do you want to use `myrand` again ? Wouldn't `mt_rand(1,7)` be easier ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a function named `rand()` in PHP to do this. Try below code:

```
function newrand() {
    return rand(1, 7);
}
```

Or lets say your `myrand()` is something like this below code:

```
function myrand() {  return rand(1,5); }
```

What you can do is, pass the upperlimit to `myrand()` something like `myrand(5)` and `myrand(7)` instead of `myrand() + 2`. Eg below:

```
myrand($max) {
     return rand(1, $max);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
function newrand() {
    return myrand(7);
}
```

Comment: Great.... but what if the number returned by `newrand()` is the same as the one returned by OP's original function `myrand()`?  The range is so small (from  0 to 7) so there is a higher chance of the returned values being exactly the same... but Up+ for the bright idea though...

Comment: That's why you got the Up+.... however, you could just take that Duplicate into consideration - though the OP didn't explicitly ask for it....  if he had wanted duplicates, he would have used the same number returned by his `myrand()` Function.... **in Brief, you are right..**. but ***you could just add that extra Logic - if you will***

Comment: Your function might return `0`, which the OP doesn't seem to want.

Comment: @roberto06      Your observation is perfect. However, the OP should be smart enough to know to change the `minBound`  (currently at `0`) to `1` if he doesn't need a zero....

Comment: @AniketSahrawat      That didn't take you that much of a time.... ***Brilliant.....*** ... honestly, much better....

Answer (score 0):

When you're writing some kind of a `rand()` function, it's better to think about binary numbers representation than just regular numbers.

For example, to get a random number in range from 0 to 7 you have to get an equal distribution of 3 bits.

```
000  # 0
001  # 1
010  # 2
...
111  # 7
```

If you can consider your `myrand()` as a function that produces numbers from 1 to 5 with equal probability, then you can construct any `rand()` functions by combining first 2 bits produced by `myrand()` calls.

```
func rand_bits_2() { return (myrand() - 1) & 0b11; }

func rand_bits_4() {
    hi = rand_bits_2() << 2;  // first 2 random bits
    lo = rand_bits_2();       // consecutive 2 random bits
    return hi | lo; 
}
```

And 4 random bits produce numbers from 0 to 15. Taking this idea further you can get for example `myrand7()`.

*UPD:* You can find more [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implement-rand3-using-rand2/).

Comment: A Bright and Unique approach but nonetheless, a little too **Heavy** for someone with an SO Reputation of less than 70 and who is still grappling with the standard PHP `rand()` Function and may not even have the slightest knowledge of ***Low-Level Bit Manipulation***... but Nice Post for those Visitors who are keen on exploring the unusual.... or the ***Unconventional*** if you prefer **:-)**

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your function uniformly generates numbers between `1` and `5`. To uniformly generate numbers between `1` and `7` do the following:

1. **Generate `7` random numbers**

   x1 ... x7

between `1` and `5` using your function

2. **Calculate the sum of the sample**

   s = x1 + x2 + ... + x7
3. **Return**

   (s - 7 mod 7) + 1

where `(s - 7 mod 7)` is the non-negative reminder of the integer division of `s - 7` by `7`.

---

Here is an example of the random frequencies I just obtained after generating `100000` samples repeating the 3 steps above such a number of times:

```
1 -> 14331
2 -> 14447
3 -> 14489
4 -> 14095
5 -> 14293
6 -> 14157
7 -> 14188
```

which, as you can see, looks clearly uniform.